# Prevent jQuery UI slider equal values

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want to prevent jQuery-UI slider equal values. The text is set as I want but the slider max value is not update as I change the value. If you slide from min to max it is working and it sets the max value to `value+step`.
But if you slide from max to min it allows the slider positions to be on the same place...

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gmdrm4zw/4/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated slide callback function for prevent min and max same value. please [click here](https://jsfiddle.net/pfjna7c6/)

```
 slide: function (event, ui){
     if(ui.values[0] == ui.values[1])
        return false;
     .......
     .......
```